# Convert symmetrically mixed type-multiindex to integer multiindex

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a long dataframe originating from a symmetric wide matrix, e.g. like in this case `date x observation_unit`

```
         2015-01-01  2015-01-02  2015-01-03
1        0           1           3
…        …           …
N        2           2           3
```

…which has been turned into a long df like so,

```
date         observation_unit    value
2015-01-01   1                   0
2015-01-02   1                   1
2015-01-03   1                   3
…
2015-01-01   N                   2
2015-01-02   N                   2
2015-01-03   N                   3
```

What is the quickest way in pandas to quickly convert these indices to integer indicies starting at 1 like so:

```
date         observation_unit    value
1            1                   0
2            1                   1
3            1                   1
…
1            N                   2
2            N                   2
3            N                   3
```

Comment: can you add more values? What is `df.info()` ?

Comment: @jezrael clarified things now a bit (realized a typo!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you simpliest is columns are unique is assign array created by `arrange`:

```
df.columns = np.arange(1,len(df.columns) + 1)
df = df.unstack()
```

For multindex use [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html) if values are not unique:

```
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([pd.factorize(df.index.get_level_values(0))[0] + 1,
                                      df.index.get_level_values(1)], names=df.index.names)
print (df)
                       value
date observation_unit       
1    1                     0
2    1                     1
3    1                     3
1    N                     2
2    N                     2
3    N                     3
```

Or:

```
df.index = [pd.factorize(df.index.get_level_values(0))[0] + 1,
            df.index.get_level_values(1)]
print (df)
                    value
  observation_unit       
1 1                     0
2 1                     1
3 1                     3
1 N                     2
2 N                     2
3 N                     3
```

Or:

```
a =  pd.factorize(df.index.levels[0])[0] + 1
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([a, df.index.levels[1]], names=df.index.names)
print (df)
                       value
date observation_unit       
1    1                     0
     N                     1
2    1                     3
     N                     2
3    1                     2
     N                     3
```

Or simplier:

```
a =  np.arange(1, len(df.index.levels[0]) + 1)
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([a, df.index.levels[1]], names=df.index.names)
print (df)
                       value
date observation_unit       
1    1                     0
     N                     1
2    1                     3
     N                     2
3    1                     2
     N                     3
```

Comment: Yes, check my solution for multiindex.

Comment: How would you factorize an arbitrary size MultiIndex? (Where each column is factorized indepently?) Looking to factorize the observation_unit-column as well :-) (and potentially more columns)

Comment: I am not sure if understand, but if need unique values to `int`s  simpliest is assign new array by `np.arrange`,but if duplicates need `factorize`/

Comment: ah yes, the dates and observation_units are unique. I see.

Comment: is there a way to avoid looping over `np.arange(1, len(df.index.levels[0]) + 1)` … `np.arange(1, len(df.index.levels[n]) + 1)`?

Comment: I think you can use list comprehenion only.

Comment: So `mux = [np.arange(1, len(df.index.levels[x]) + 1) for x in np.arange(df.index.nlevels)]`,
`df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(mux, names=df.index.names)`

Answer (score 1):

Quickest way would be to use `pd.factorize`

```
df.date = pd.factorize(df.date)[0] + 1

df

   date observation_unit  value
0     1                1      0
1     2                1      1
2     3                1      3
3     1                N      2
4     2                N      2
5     3                N      3
```

---

In fact, if I were starting with a dataframe `df` equal to the following

```
   2015-01-01  2015-01-02  2015-01-03
1           0           1           3
N           2           2           3
```

I'd transform it like this:

```
df.columns = pd.factorize(df.columns)[0] + 1
df.stack().rename_axis(['observation_unit', 'date']).reset_index(name='value')

  observation_unit  date  value
0                1     1      0
1                1     2      1
2                1     3      3
3                N     1      2
4                N     2      2
5                N     3      3
```

Comment: This is really elegant — is it possible to use on the index?

Comment: @salient yes!  absolutely.

Comment: salient - check my answer.